# Проблема с обновлением сертификата letsencrypt Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, letsencrypt

При установке сертификата ошибок не обнаружил, а вот при обновлении получил ошибку.

Вот такой вывод:

```
Checking for new version...
Creating virtual environment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in 
main()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
download=download,
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 918, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 812, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/christian/.loc...ncrypt/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Попробуйте удалить letsencrypt и установить заново? (Каталог с настройками и сертификатами `/etc/letsencrypt` трогать не надо, разумеется)

Comment: Пробовал, ошибка была не в скрипте как оказалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел аналогичную ошибку, вызывалась она другой программой - [certbot](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2883#issuecomment-216427925)
но её решение мне помогло. 
Проблема была в локальных переменных,для её решения нужно было прописать следующее:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Использовал скрипт: [letsencrypt.sh](https://github.com/gheift/letsencrypt.sh)

Comment: `certbot` и `letsencrypt` — это одна и та же программа, только `certbot` новая версия, а `letsencrypt` старая